# Azure CLI inline parameters not working

Tags: json, node.js, powershell, azure, azure-cli

I'm trying to pass in parameters inline to a ARM template from within PowerShell using the following command:

```
azure group deployment create -f my_arm_template.json -g myresourcegroup -p '{\"slot\":\"blue\"}' --verbose
```

and receive the error:

```
Error converting value "blue" to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Data.Definitions.DeploymentParameterDefinition'. Path 'properties.parameters.slot'
```

I'm using the example given from this page:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-template-deploy/

I have tried without escaping the quotes just like the example and various other ways but every other attempt breaks when trying to validate my template.

UPDATE 1: I have tried this from CMD in addition to Powershell with the same results.

Comment: If you're going to down vote, at least provide an explanation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem wasn't the way I was escaping the JSON but it was the value I was giving. Instead of:

```
{"slot":"blue"}
```

it should have been:

```
{"slot":{"value":"blue"}}
```

Comment: Ugh, so frustrating... Thanks for the answer!